# How could I parse data coming in a custom format?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Could somebody please help me parse this in Delphi?  I am receiving data in the following format:

```
Data = {
    ["Node 1 Name"] = {
        ["Item 1 Name"] = {"short name", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},
        ["Item 2 Name"] = {"short name", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},
    },
    ["Node 2 Name"] = {
        ["Item 1 Name"] = {"short name", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},
        ["Item 2 Name"] = {"short name", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},
    },
    ["Node 3 Name"] = {
        ["Item 1 Name"] = {"short name", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},
        ["Item 2 Name"] = {"short name", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},
    }
}
```

Basically, I need to be able to get all nodes (their names), and all item names associated for each node with their short name and description. The number of items and nodes could be variable. This is the final structure, the data can't have any more levels or values.

Comment: You'd need to know what the rules for this format are. I'd consult whoever supplies the data. But most people who ask here would probably just plough on without doing that, and write something that converts the two example files that they have to hand and think the job is done. I guess I'm getting a bit jaded.....

Comment: The first question is: Is the example you show cover all possible cases? This looks like a tree and you show two levels. Maybe there are more? As David said, try to get the specifications for the format. Without it, even if someone makes a parser (Not much difficult for that exact format), the risk is that it doesn't work for all cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I designed a very simple parser for the data you showed in your question.

It is in his own unit I named `ParseCustomDataParser` for the demo.

To use it, you add ParseCustomDataParser in the uses clause of your source code (Probably a TForm). And then you may use it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
    SampleData : String =
        'Data = {' +
        '    ["Node 1 Name"] = {' +
        '        ["Item 1 Name"] = {"short name 1/1", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},' +
        '        ["Item 2 Name"] = {"short name 1/2", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},' +
        '    },' +
        '    ["Node 2 Name"] = {' +
        '        ["Item 1 Name"] = {"short name 2/1", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},' +
        '        ["Item 2 Name"] = {"short name 2/2", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},' +
        '    },' +
        '    ["Node 3 Name"] = {' +
        '        ["Item 1 Name"] = {"short name 3/1", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},' +
        '        ["Item 2 Name"] = {"short name 3/2", "Description here, which could include [] brackets"},' +
        '    }' +
        '}';
var
    Index      : Integer;
    NRow       : Integer;
    NItem      : Integer;
    CustomData : TCustomData;
begin
    // Parse the source of data
    try
        Index := 1;
        CustomData.Parse(SampleData, Index);
    except
        on E:Exception do begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
            Exit;
        end;
    end;

    // Display the parsed result
    Memo1.Lines.Add(CustomData.Name);
    for NRow := 0 to High(CustomData.Rows) do begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('  ' + CustomData.Rows[NRow].Name);
        for NItem := 0 to High(CustomData.Rows[NRow].Items) do begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(
                '    Name="' + CustomData.Rows[NRow].Items[NItem].ShortName + '"' +
                '    Description="' + CustomData.Rows[NRow].Items[NItem].Description + '"');
        end;
    end;
end;
```

The parser takes a string as source of data and an index into the string where to start (Should be 1 probably).

The parsing is implemented as a method of the record `TCustomData` containing the result. That record contains an array of rows each made of an array of items.

I made a number of assumptions about the format because you just showed an example but no complete specification. For example, I assumed - for simplicity - that strings in double quotes do not contain the character double quote itself. Another example, is that your sample data has an extrax coma at the end of item list while the should not be one. I just ignore that extra coma if present. There are many other details that you should take care of to make a real world code from mine. That's the best I could do given there are no specification. You are started. It's now up to you to build your solution based on my code.

The parser source code:

```
unit ParseCustomDataParser;

interface

uses
    System.SysUtils;

const
    UnexpectedDelimiter = 'Unexpected delimiter at index %d "%s", ' +
                          'should be "%s"';

type
  TCustomDataItem = record
      Name        : String;
      ShortName   : String;
      Description : String;
      procedure Clear;
      procedure Parse(const Src : String; var Index : Integer);
  end;
  TCustomDataRow = record
      Name  : String;
      Items : array of TCustomDataItem;
      procedure Clear;
      procedure Parse(const Src : String; var Index : Integer);
  end;
  TCustomData = record
      Name : String;
      Rows : array of TCustomDataRow;
      procedure Clear;
      procedure Parse(const Src : String; var Index : Integer);
  end;


implementation

{ Support routines }

procedure SkipSpaces(const Src : String; var Index : Integer);
begin
    while (Index <= Length(Src)) and
          (CharInSet(Src[Index], [' ', #9, #10, #13])) do
        Inc(Index);
end;

function GetNextDelimiter(const Src : String; var Index : Integer) : Char;
begin
    SkipSpaces(Src, Index);
    if Index > Length(Src) then
        Result := #0
    else begin
        Result := Src[Index];
        Inc(Index);
    end;
end;

function GetNextToken(const Src : String; var Index : Integer) : String;
var
    N : Integer;
begin
    SkipSpaces(Src, Index);
    N := Index;
    while (Index <= Length(Src)) and
          (CharInSet(Src[Index], ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'])) do
        Inc(Index);
    Result := Copy(Src, N, Index - N);
end;

function GetNextQuotedString(const Src : String; var Index : Integer) : String;
var
    Delimiter : Char;
    N         : Integer;
begin
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '"' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '"']);
    N := Index;
    // Find closing double quote
    while (Index <= Length(Src)) and (Src[Index] <> '"') do
        Inc(Index);
    Result := Copy(Src, N, Index - N);
    if (Index <= Length(Src)) and (Src[Index] = '"') then
        Inc(Index);   // Skip closing double quote
end;

{ TCustomData }

procedure TCustomData.Clear;
begin
    Name := '';
    SetLength(Rows, 0);
end;

procedure TCustomData.Parse(const Src: String; var Index : Integer);
var
    Token     : String;
    Delimiter : Char;
    NRow      : Integer;
begin
    Clear;
    while Index <= Length(Src) do begin
        Token := GetNextToken(Src, Index);
        if Token = '' then
           break;
        Name := Token;
        Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
        if Delimiter <> '=' then
            raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                      [Index, Delimiter, '=']);
        Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
        if Delimiter <> '{' then
            raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                      [Index, Delimiter, '{']);
        while TRUE do begin
            // Add a new row
            NRow := Length(Rows);
            SetLength(Rows, NRow + 1);
            Rows[NRow].Parse(Src, Index);
            Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
            if Delimiter <> '}' then
                raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                          [Index, Delimiter, '{']);
            Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
            if Delimiter <> ',' then begin
                Dec(Index);
                break;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;

{ TCustomDataRow }

procedure TCustomDataRow.Clear;
begin
    Name := '';
    SetLength(Items, 0);
end;

procedure TCustomDataRow.Parse(const Src: String; var Index : Integer);
var
    Delimiter    : Char;
    QuotedString : String;
    NRow         : Integer;
begin
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '[' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '[']);
    QuotedString := GetNextQuotedString(Src, Index);
    if QuotedString = '' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Missing quoted string at index %d', [Index]);
    Name := QuotedString;
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> ']' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, ']']);
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '=' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '=']);
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '{' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '{']);
    while TRUE do begin
        NRow := Length(Items);
        SetLength(Items, NRow + 1);
        Items[NRow].Parse(Src, Index);
        Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
        if Delimiter <> ',' then begin
            Dec(Index);   // Go back to the delimiter
            break;
        end;
        // Last item is allowed to have an extra coma
        Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
        Dec(Index);   // Go back to the delimiter
        if Delimiter <> '[' then
            break;
    end;
end;

{ TCustomDataItem }

procedure TCustomDataItem.Clear;
begin
    Name        := '';
    ShortName   := '';
    Description := '';
end;

procedure TCustomDataItem.Parse(const Src: String; var Index: Integer);
var
    Delimiter    : Char;
    QuotedString : String;
begin
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '[' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '[']);
    QuotedString := GetNextQuotedString(Src, Index);
    if QuotedString = '' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Missing quoted string at index %d', [Index]);
    Name := QuotedString;
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> ']' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, ']']);
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '=' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '=']);
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '{' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '{']);
    QuotedString := GetNextQuotedString(Src, Index);
    if QuotedString = '' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Missing quoted string at index %d', [Index]);
    ShortName := QuotedString;
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> ',' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, ',']);
    QuotedString := GetNextQuotedString(Src, Index);
    if QuotedString = '' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Missing quoted string at index %d', [Index]);
    Description := QuotedString;
    Delimiter := GetNextDelimiter(Src, Index);
    if Delimiter <> '}' then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(UnexpectedDelimiter,
                                  [Index, Delimiter, '}']);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I need. I really appreciate you taking your time for this. As a PS to your comment, yes, this covers all cases, the tree doesn't go any deeper and there aren't any more fields either. Just more items or nodes, I've posted only two so people can get an idea and so I wouldn't spam the post too much.
PPS: I've just noticed you're the creator of ICS so I had to re-post my comment with an extra thank you for that - I didn't use Delphi in ages, but your components were the first I ever used for a network application. Your work is appreciated!